# Should UserManager be manually disposed in Blazor Server, and how to recreate new instance?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

Please correct me if I am wrong, unlike MVC/WASM, in Blazor Server, a scoped service is shared across all child components inside the same Razor component. A typical example is **DbContext**, which according the Microsoft's [recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0#scope-to-the-component-lifetime), should be created inside each component by a **IDbContextFactory** registered as **Singleton** by default in startup. Something like:

```
// demo.razor
@inject IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> DbFactory
@implements IAsyncDisposable

@code {

    private MyDbContext _context = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _context = await DbFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
        //do something...
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
    async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync() {
        if (_context is not null)
        {
            await _context.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
```

Now comes the question that should UserManager be created and disposed the same way as **DbContext**? I understand now that UserManager has a public **Dispose** method, it should be disposed when we are done with it.

But if we call its **Dispose** method inside a Razor component, all other child components in the same component will not be able to access this UserManager any more, since the **UserManager** is the same instance within the scope.

I have not found something like **IUserManagerFactory** to create a new instance of **UserManager** for a component. Or just don't call **UserManager.Dispose()** and let the framework handle it?